# How can I use DrawText() to display a variable?

Tags: c++, variables, drawtext

I can draw a string literal via `DrawText()`:

```
DrawText (hdcWindow, "abc123", -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE);
```

However, this doesn't work with anything else. Specifically, I can't output the value stored in a variable, such as an `int`:

```
int variable = 5;
DrawText (hdcWindow, variable, -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE);
```

Or a `char`:

```
char variable = a;
DrawText (hdcWindow, variable, -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE);
```

How can I use `DrawText()` to display the contents of a variable? Why does using a string literal like `"abc123"` work but substituting it with `variable` doesn't?

Comment: There are lots of examples of converting an int to a string, and a constructor of `string` that takes a `char` and a size.

Comment: Repost : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518784/how-to-use-d-in-c-particularly-in-drawtext?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DrawText` only knows how to display character strings. To display anything else, you need to convert to a character string first, then display that.

```
void show_int(int x, /* ... */) { 
     std::stringstream buffer;
     buffer << x;

     DrawText(hdcWindow, buffer.str().c_str(), -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE);
}
```

Comment: what do i need to include? (#include)

Comment: @JacobPadgett, `<sstream>`

Comment: do you know where i can get it? because my dev-cpp didnt come with it. Thank you, as well, Chris!

Comment: @JacobPadgett, It must be pretty old then, but there's the outdated `strstream`. There's also `boost::lexical_cast` if you have Boost.

Comment: i will use it then. thank you guys. we are all done now, i think.